# Chars problems converting HTML to PDF

Tags: java, html, pdf

I can't get special chars in my PDF from html. I tried to  use UTF-8 reading, Windows-1257, ISO-8859-13 and etc. But nothing works, instead I just get spaces.

So the question is how to fix that?

JAVA

```
    String d1 = "<html><head></head><body>...ą...č...ę...ė...į...š...ų...ū...ž...Ą...Č...Ę...Ė...Į...Š...Ų...Ū...Ž...</body></html>";


    OutputStream myFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\My\\pdf1.pdf"));
    Document document = new Document();

    document.addCreationDate();
    document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
    document.setMargins(36, 36, 36, 36);
    document.setMarginMirroring(true);


    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, myFile);
    document.open();

    XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

    InputStream is;
    //is = new ByteArrayInputStream(d1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    is = new ByteArrayInputStream(d1.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    String FONT = "C:\\My\\FreeSans.ttf";
    XMLWorkerFontProvider fontImp = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
    fontImp.register(FONT);

    worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), fontImp);

    document.close();
    myFile.close();
```

Comment: Is the `style`-attribute not missing in the `body`-tag of your html? `String d1 = "<html><head></head><body style=\"font-family: FreeSans\">...ą...č...ę...ė...į...š...ų...ū...ž...Ą...Č...Ę...Ė...Į...Š...Ų...Ū...Ž...</body></html>";`

Answer (score 0):

Topaco right, after I add in my string "body style..." everything works perfectly!